# How to display columns with different rules using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There are 3 columns in a paragraph element:

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.column {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="foo">
  <span class="first column">first</span>
  <span class="second column">second</span>
  <span class="third column">third</span>
</p>
```

The rules are:

- 3 columns should display in only one row and each of them is possible to have huge characters in there.
- the first column max-width is 70%
- the second column max-width is 50px
- the third column can be displayed none if the first and second column takes the whole row

I don't know how to do it by using flex to achieve this. Can someone give me some solution about it?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.foo {
    display: flex;
}

.first  { flex: 0 1 70%; }        /* can't grow, can shrink, max width 70% */

.second { flex: 0 1 50px; }       /* can't grow, can shrink, max width 50px */

.column {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="foo">
    <span class="first column">first first first first first first first first first first first first first first first first first first first</span>
    <span class="second column">second second second second second second second second second </span>
    <span class="third column">third third third third third third</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, this solution doesnt conform to last rule, can you have a look

Comment: You are right for minimal 320px :). But it seems that third column breaks ratio if it is too wide. https://jsfiddle.net/ddd3130/xtjhvkLo/

Comment: If you remove `flex-shrink: 1` from columns 1 & 2, they will retain their full-length. https://jsfiddle.net/xtjhvkLo/1/

Comment: Yep, changing shrink from 1 to 0 fix that issue. Another issue is the first column always take 70% as basis, how can I change it to be adaptable based on the content https://jsfiddle.net/ddd3130/xtjhvkLo/3/